# How to get Length, width and Height from 8 vertices?

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

I parsed CAD file and got following vertices for solid rectangular hollow body called duct.
with following vertices

(1512,-8027, 1973)
(1512,-7027,1973)
(1512,-7027,2973)
(1512,-8027,2973)
(1675,-8027,1973)
(1675,-7027,1973)
(1675,-7027,2973)
(1675,-8027,2973)

How to get its length/height/width?

Comment: It would be nice to refer some library for the purpose, I have multiple shapes of duct with different number of vertices 8, 32, 88

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have matrix $a$ $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1512&-8027&1973\\
1512&-7027&1973\\
1512&-7027&2973\\
1512&-8027&2973\\
1675&-8027&1973\\
1675&-7027&1973\\
1675&-7027&2973\\
1675&-8027&2973\\
\end{array}\right]$$ As a first step I would suggest subtracting $1512$ from the first coordinate, adding $8027$ to the second coordinate and subtracting $1973$ from the third coordinate. This operation leave your body intact as it amounts to simple shift in the origin. After you do this you get matrix $a'$ $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0&0&0\\
0&1000&0\\
0&1000&1000\\
0&0&1000\\
163&0&0\\
163&1000&0\\
163&1000&1000\\
163&0&1000\\\end{array}\right]$$ so that your body is $163\times1000\times1000$.